# Updating record from one table with sum of current record plus another tables record

Tags: mysql, sql

I am attempting to update a record in my table with the sum of two records from different tables. So far I have this however it doesnt appear to work.

```
    UPDATE StockCatalog
    SET StockCatalog.ProductQuantity = (StockCatalog.ProductQuantity + DeliveryContent.DeliveryQuantity)
    FROM StockCatalog
    INNER JOIN DeliveryContent on StockCatalog.StockID = DeliveryContent.StockID
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 UPDATE StockCatalog
 INNER JOIN DeliveryContent on StockCatalog.StockID = DeliveryContent.StockID
 SET StockCatalog.ProductQuantity = (StockCatalog.ProductQuantity +  DeliveryContent.DeliveryQuantity)
```